# C++ ReSharper - generating a variable of function's return value / parameter type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, resharper-2016, visual-assist-x

Isn't there a ReSharper 2016 C++/VisualAssist X C++/VS 2015 shortcut for generating a variable of function's return value / specific parameter type?

(I'm not talking about `auto`, I mean the actual type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a variable name in place, then you can use Visual Assist's "Create From Usage" command to do this.  Using the very simple test case:

```
std::pair<int, long> getPairsOfNumbers();

void testingNewVariableForFunctionReturn()
{
    pairVar = getPairsOfNumbers();
}
```

Create From Usage on the unknown symbol "pairVar" gives you the option to create a new local variable of the correct type.  Alt-Shift-Q is the default keyboard shortcut for the refactoring context menu, once you have placed the caret into the variable name.

Create From Usage documentation here:
https://wholetomato.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W164

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper C++ has "Introduce Variable" refactoring for that purpose. Similar to VAX, you can also use "Create local variable"/"Create global variable"/"Create field" quick fixes.